# Can't implement both GetEnumerator return IEnumerator AND IEnumerator<T> when implementing ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm writing a simple collection class that implements `ICollection<T>`. Everything basically works except if I add a `IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()` method it complains I don't have an `IEnumerator GetEnumerator()` method. And vice versa. I'm not allowed to have both since they differ only in return type, so I'm really quite confused as to what the compiler wants from me.

Here are the errors precisely as they are given to me:

> error CS0738: `MyClass<T>' does not implement interface member`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' and the best implementing candidate `MyClass<T>.GetEnumerator()' return type`System.Collections.IEnumerator' does not match interface member return type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator'

OR, alternatively I can have:

> error CS0738: `MyClass<T>' does not implement interface member`System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' and the best implementing candidate `MyClass<T>.GetEnumerator()' return type`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator' does not match interface member return type `System.Collections.IEnumerator'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why implement IEnumerable(T) if I can just define ONE GetEnumerator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737997/why-implement-ienumerablet-if-i-can-just-define-one-getenumerator)

Comment: If your ICollection<T>'s T is the same as your IEnumerable<T>'s T you probably don't want to add the IEnumerabl<T> as ICollection<T> inherits from that already. Unless they are different then explicit implementation is correct. (even though I got downvoted into oblivion, less redundant code = better maintainability. Consider it)

Comment: Just google the error first. Here is a duplicate: [Troubles implementing IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760322/troubles-implementing-ienumerablet)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement them explicitly:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
}

IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() {
}

// etc.
```

Explicit interface implementation is how this is achieved. Read about it on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: You probably don't want the IEnumerable<T> version to be explicit.

Answer (score 3):

Use [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx). That's exactly how `List<T>` implements both `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`, pointing to third `GetEnumerator` method:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return new List<T>.Enumerator(this);
}

IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
{
    return new List<T>.Enumerator(this);
}

public List<T>.Enumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return new List<T>.Enumerator(this);
}
```

With that kind of declaration you can have couple methods with the same name - as long as they implement some interface method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I upvoted you but the other similar answer came a minute earlier

Comment: @FranciscoRyanTolmaskyI It was 1:27 after mine, but that's OK :) The most important thing is you solved your problem!

Answer (score -3):

ICollection extends IEnumerable. Thus you don't want to do IEnumerable on your class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx

Comment: It solves the problem by identifying that you don't need IEnumberable<T> and ICollection<T> if T is the same.

Comment: ICollection<T> is an interface. It doesn't provide any implementation.

Comment: Obviously, but since it inherits from IEnumerable, you get the GetEnumerator function already, you don't need to implement it twice unless the T's specified above are not the same. Then It would make sense to do both.

Comment: It inherits from IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T>. These are two interfaces that define two functions called GetEnumerator. The functions have different signatures and therefore need individual implementations. Since ICollection<T> is an interface, it doesn't provide any implementation.