# Immutable objects in PHP?

Tags: php, class, immutability

Is it a good idea to create objects that cannot be changed in PHP?

For example a date object which has setter methods, but they will always return a new instance of the object (with the modified date).

Would these objects be confusing to other people that use the class, because in PHP you usually expect the object to change?

Example

```
$obj = new Object(2);

$x = $obj->add(5); // 7
$y = $obj->add(2); // 4
```

Comment: Do you see any benefit in having classes that do this? I'd probably consider a better approach would be to simply deny *settability* (yes I made that up) on properties you don't want changing, forcing them to create a new instance if required. EDIT: Yea, what ThiefMaster said :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317037/php-immutable-public-member-fields

this example can help you to understend

Comment: Hope that immutability feature will come soon https://wiki.php.net/rfc/immutability

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An immutable object cannot be changed after its initial creation so having setter methods makes no sense as it goes against that base principle.

You could implement some workarounds to simulate immutability in PHP by manipulating class member visibility and overriding the magic `__set()` method but its not guaranteed immutable as immutability is not a feature of the PHP language.

I believe someone once wrote an extension to provide an immutable value type in PHP though so you could google for that.

Comment: Regarding "having setter methods makes no sense": a method `add` (like the one mentioned in the question) may have sense in an immutable object by returning a new object with the modified state.

Answer (score 30):

Immutable objects don't have setter methods. Period.

Everyone will expect a `setXyz()` method to have a void return type (or return nothing in loosely typed languages). If you do add setter methods to your immutable object it will confuse the hell out of people and lead to ugly bugs.

Comment: well they wouldn't be called like set(), but I don't know how to call them. addetter methods? :)

Comment: Although some amongst those "Everyone" won't be surprised to receive an instance of the setter's object, to allow for method chaining ;-)

Comment: @Elfy Call them "with" methods. `$obj->withMyProp($x)` returns a new instance *with* "MyProp" set to `$x`.

Comment: Indeed. In Java, that's pretty common [\[1\]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#withMonth-int-),[\[2\]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9570112/507738).

Comment: This is the correct answer for all sane programming languages. But this is about PHP after all. PHP has glorious methods like `DateTimeImmutable::setTime()` in its core... It makes my head spin.

Answer (score 16):

In my opinion objects should be immutable for value objects. Other than that it does not have much benefits unless you're sharing your object across your whole application.

There is some wrong answers here, **an immutable object can have setters**. Here's some implementation of immutable objects in PHP.

Example #1.

```
class ImmutableValueObject
{
    private $val1;
    private $val2;

    public function __construct($val1, $val2)
    {
        $this->val1 = $val1;
        $this->val2 = $val2;
    }

    public function getVal1()
    {
        return $this->val1;
    }

    public function getVal2()
    {
        return $this->val2;
    }
}
```

As you can see once instantiated you cannot changed any value.

Example 2: with `setters`:

```
class ImmutableValueObject
{
    private $val1;
    private $val2;

    public function __construct($val1, $val2)
    {
        $this->val1 = $val1;
        $this->val2 = $val2;
    }

    public function getVal1()
    {
        return $this->val1;
    }

    public function withVal1($val1)
    {
        $copy = clone $this;
        $copy->val1 = $val1;

        return $copy;    // here's the trick: you return a new instance!
    }

    public function getVal2()
    {
        return $this->val2;
    }

    public function withVal2($val2)
    {
        $copy = clone $this;
        $copy->val2 = $val2;

        return $copy;
    }
}
```

There is several implementation possible and this is by no means an exclusive list. And remember that with Reflection there is always a way to get around that in PHP, so immutability is all in your head in the end!

It is also often good practice to put immutable objects as final.

EDIT:

- changed setX for withX
- added comment about final

Comment: Should  `return $this;` actually return `$copy`?

Comment: "In computer science, a mutator method is a method used to control changes to a variable. They are also widely known as setter methods".__An immutable object can't have setters__. His methods don't change internal state of the object. __They just creates a new instance__. That's a big different.

Comment: Also using 'setX' or 'changeX' names is a bad idea. These names strongly suggest that the internal state of the object will change. It's not true. Better practice is using for example 'withX'.

Comment: > _An immutable object can't have setters__. His methods don't change internal state of the object. They just creates a new instance.

Agreed, and that's what this setters do in this immutable object. Although I agree, having setX or changeX is a wrong naming for it in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Making object immutable in PHP is pretty easy. Here is an elegant and convenient approach.

All you need to do is to create the base abstract class with the specific `__get()` and `__set()` magic methods and extend this base class in the child object.

This is quite applicable if you use value objects (e.g. for DDD).

Here is the base class:

```php
abstract class BaseValueObject
{
    public function __get(string $propertyName)
    {
        return $this->$propertyName;
    }

    public function __set(string $propertyName, $value): void
    {
        throw new \Exception("Cannot set property {$propertyName}. The object is immutable.");
    }
}
```

Now a child object (well, its class).

```php
class CategoryVO extends BaseValueObject
{

    public $id;
    public $name;

    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->id = $data['id'];
        $this->name = $data['name'];
    }
}
```

It would throw an exception at attempt to set some value. Basically it is immutable.

This is it.

Make as many immutable objects as you need. Create the new objects via constructor. Dispose them and re-create the new ones when needed (add a specific creator method if required, a static or an instance one, to the base class or to the extended one).

Yet such an object would conveniently expose all its properties as read-only (for some kind of serialization or the like), unlike if we would have made them private (but even though we could use [JsonSerializable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface to make the serialization as flexible as we need with private properties or even more drastic transformations).

Finally one cannot mistakenly instantiate `BaseValueObject` as it is an abstract class. From all standpoints nice elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little trait avoiding using Reflection to ease the implementation of immutability: https://github.com/jclaveau/php-immutable-trait

Obviously, as it's not a language feature, it won't impeach mutation by magic but lighten the code of the mutators that must clone the current instance before being applied. Applied to Massimiliano's example it would produce

```
class ImmutableValueObject
{
    use JClaveau\Traits\Immutable;

    private $val1;
    private $val2;

    public function __construct($val1, $val2)
    {
        $this->val1 = $val1;
        $this->val2 = $val2;
    }

    public function getVal1()
    {
        return $this->val1;
    }

    public function withVal1($val1)
    {
        // Just add these lines at the really beginning of methods supporting
        // immutability ("setters" mostly)
        if ($this->callOnCloneIfImmutable($result))
            return $result;

        // Write your method's body as if you weren't in an Immutable class
        $this->val1 = $val1;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getVal2()
    {
        return $this->val2;
    }

    public function withVal2($val2)
    {
        if ($this->callOnCloneIfImmutable($result))
            return $result;

        $this->val2 = $val2;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

- You can see that you don't return $copy here but $this as Kanstantsin K noticed.
- In native PHP https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php has mutators that will return new instances with modification applied. So copy pasting sentences saying that immutable objects shouldn't have mutators doesn't seem super interesting.
- The practice of using "withXXX" instead of "setXXX" is super interesting, thanks for the suggestion! I personnaly used "becomesXXX" for the api chainging the mutability of the instance (optionnal API in the trait SwitchableMutability).

Hoping it can help some people here!

PS: Suggestions on this little feature are really welcome :) : https://github.com/jclaveau/php-immutable-trait/issues

Answer (score 0):

From an immutable object, you can get its values but there is no way to modify them. Here you can see an example of an immutable class:

```
<?php 

declare(strict_types=1);

final class Immutable 
{
    /** @var string */
    private $value;

    public static function withValue(string $value): self
    {
        return new self($value);
    }

    public function __construct(string $value) 
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function value(): string 
    { 
        return $this->value;
    }
}

// Example of usage:
$immutable = Immutable::withValue("my value");
$immutable->value();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want setters on a class and object this is perfectly fine, we do this all of the time as we need to set object data. Just simply don't call it immutable.

Many things in the dev world are subjective - our approaches, methodology etc - but "immutable" is a pretty solid definition:

> "Immutable":
>   - Unchanging over time or unable to be changed.

If you want an immutable object it means it cannot be changed after instantiation. This is good for things such as data from a DB that needs to remain set in stone for the duration of the cycle.

If you need to call the object and set or change data on it after instantiation, this is not an immutable object.

Would you take 2 wheels off a car and calling it a motorbike?

There is some talk about methods on an "immutable" class being named without the word "set", but this doesn't stop the functionality of them being a method that sets data. You could call it `thisDoesNotSetAnything(int $id)` and allow data to be passed in which changes the object. It'll be a setter, and thus the object is mutable.